# How to Decide the Parameters of A Simple Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I want to train the CNN with my own data set (it's not for image classification), but I'm new to CNN, the parameters in the sample code really confused me. I have tried to change the parameters but failed.

Each of the sample in my training data is 205*8=1640 (8 rows by 205 columns),
I there are only 2 classes(target and nontarget).

But I'm not sure how to set the parameters of the code below to fit my data set.

**here is a part of the source code(I borrowed it)**

**this code is for classifying 28*28 MINST images into 10 classes**

```
n_classes = 2
batch_size = 128

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 1640])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

def maxpool2d(x):
#                           size of window      movement of window
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

def convolutional_neural_network(x):
    weights = {'W_Conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
               'W_Conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
               'W_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024])),
               'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))}

    biases = {'b_Conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
              'b_Conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
              'b_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
              'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['W_Conv1'])
conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)

conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['W_Conv2'])
conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)

fc = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, 7*7*64])
fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc']) + biases['b_fc'])

output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out']) + biases['out']

return output
```

Comment: The code you provided simply creates the graph, you do not have any training loop, which "figures out the parameters". You should go through TF tutorials, as this is literally what they are about. Unless the question is about adapting **sizes** of the modules to fit your data?

Comment: @lejlot， yes , my question is about the sizes of the modules. This sample code is for training 28x28 image, but my data is 205x8.

Comment: WHat do you mean with "I have tried to change the parameters but failed."? What is the problem? Do you obtain an error? How you provide your data? Have you reshaped it?

Comment: You probably mean to discover good parameters for the model's structure, which are more like hyper-parameters. I'm afraid that guidance on neural network design is off-topic for SO, since it's mostly focused around machine learning and machine learning model engineering.

Comment: Can you explain what the data is?. The weights (kernels)  can be visualised as a 'torch' scanning the input for features. Here the torch is a rectangular one and you decide the size based on how much area you want to 'focus' at a point in time. Since your data is not image, you need to define what the input is and how u want to analyse. For example in text data analysis the width of the filter is same as the width of the input text when using CNN.

Comment: @vijaym the data set is eeg(electroencephalograph), each sample has 1640 datas, there are 8 channels, so each channel has 205 datas, can I just separate it by the channels to get a 205*8 matrix for each training sample

Comment: @MatthewYen if they are correlated across channels then you can do it and try apply a 2d conv with witdth fixed at 8. Try with CONV->MAXPOOL->RESHAPE->FULLY connected. If your uncomfortable setting the weights, use the tf.layers API, it will  create weight matrices for you.

Comment: @vijaym thanks very much！